# Multiset to Multiset Function in SQL / Relational Algebra

Tags: sql, relational-database, relational-algebra

It is common that a relational database supports scalar, aggregate and user-defined functions (UDFs):

```
SELECT x + 2
FROM data;

SELECT SUM(x)
FROM data;

SELECT add_2(x)
FROM data;
```

In PostgreSQL (in other languages, too, I suppose) there is also the *setof* keyword for returning tuples from a UDF.

My questions are:
Is there a class of functions that uses the multiset semantics of aggregate functions and *returns* a multiset of the same cardinality?
Is there a class of functions that extends this concept to lists?
Are there databases that cope with these features in an extended SQL already?

For example, this query shuffles all *x*'s in the group *i*. This is different to ORDER BY RANDOM() in that it first links the value *x* to a new tuple.

```
SELECT i, SHUFFLE(x)
FROM data
GROUP BY i;
```

I would be grateful to every pointer! In the meantime, I will have a look at Codd's legacy ;)

Comment: AFAIK the only notion of "tuples" in a database table are the records themselves.  Would it be possible for you to solve your problem using normal database behavior?

Comment: My aim is to push functionality into a database that does f:R^N->R^N and not f:R^n->R. A workaroud would be to put a table into a UDF and do the calculation there. But when a UDF is applied to several groups of the table, as shown above, I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Maybe ROW_NUMBER() OVER ORDER BY is the feature you are looking for? In a relational database the tables and queries always contains sets of tuples, not multisets. If you are dealing with multisets then that's because you are using SQL. SQL is non-relational and this is one of the ways in which it differs from the relational model.

Comment: Thank you, @sqlvogel, window functions solve my problem! Still, implementing user-defined window functions seems to be unusual.